# Relation between diffeomorphism and immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, compactness, smooth-manifolds

Is it always true that a local diffeomorphism is an immersion? I was thinking about the specific case of the equivalence map:

$$ \rho : (x,y,z) \longrightarrow [(x,y,z)]$$

that goes from $S^2$ to $P(\mathbb{R^2})$, the latter being the projective space for $n=2$. We know that this is a local diffeomorphism and that the sphere is compact but does that allow us to conclude that it is also an immersion? Or is it not an immersion?

Comment: Yes if something is a diffeomorphism (locally or globally) the differential at a point must be invertible (it's a linear isomorphism) which means it must be injective

Comment: A small comment: "equivalence map" is a nonstandard and misleading term. The standard terminology is "quotient map".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial with certain definitions of "immersion" and "local diffeomorphism". Let $f$ be a smooth map between manifolds.

What it means for $f$ to be an immersion is that $df_x$ is injective for all $x$.

What it means for $f$ to be a local diffeomorphism is that $df_x$ is bijective for all $x$.

Thus, a local diffeomorphism is always an immersion.

---

Another definition of "local diffeomorphism" that you may have seen is "for all points $x$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|_U$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image". The inverse function theorem says precisely that this is equivalent to the definition of "local diffeomorphism" given above.